# Create ViewStack in Actionscript with creationPolicy = "auto"

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

In MXML, when I add components to `ViewStack` and `creationPolicy` is `auto`, components are not instantiated until I switch to them. Say, I have the following code:

```
<mx:ViewStack creationPolicy="auto">
    <s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:DataGrid id="dg1" width="300"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:DataGrid id="dg2" width="100"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

How do I replicate this behavior in ActionScript?
The problem is that my DataGrids hold large chunks of data, and thus I don't want them to be created at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ViewStack class has a creationPolicy property on it. Something like this should work

```
var v:ViewStack = new ViewStack();
v.creationPolicy = "auto";


var t1:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
t1.addElement(new DataGrid());

v.addElement(t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this one

```
var v:ViewStack = new ViewStack();
v.creationPolicy = "auto";

var container:SkinnableContainer = new SkinnableContainer();
container.creationPolicy = "none";

var dg:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
container.addElement(dg);

var t1:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
t1.addElement(container);

v.addElement(t1);
```

After viewstack_change handler we need to call

`container.createDeferredContent()` based on which index view you want to see.

For more details [Using the createDeferredContent() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7aee.html#top)

Comment: Hope this will help you bit http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2009/02/12/deferred-component-instantiation-in-actionscript/